# Moving underset text closer to main text

Tags: math-mode, positioning

I have an arrow with some text directly underneath, using the command

```
\newcommand*{\tautrans}%
  {\underset{\scriptstyle \tau^*}{\longrightarrow}}%
```

Since `\tau^*` is not close enough to `\longrightarrow`, I changed to

```
\newcommand*{\tautrans}%
  {\underset{\scriptstyle \raisebox{.2em}{\ensuremath{\tau^*}}}{\longrightarrow}}%
```

Unfortunately, this changes the distance between lines, but not between `\tau^*` and `\longrightarrow`.

So how can I move `\tau^*` a little bit up without moving anything else, so that `\tau^*` comes closer to `\longrightarrow`?

Comment: What about `\underset{\smash{\scriptstyle \tau^*}}{\longrightarrow}` ?

Comment: you don't need the `\scriptstyle` -- that's the default size.  including it actually causes the `\tau` to be moved down a hair.  removing it won't move the `\tau` as close as you want, but you should omit `\scriptstyle` anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution. I defined `\tautransi` using `\xrightarrow`; the text under the arrow can be raised using a `\raisebox` (change the length according to your needs). The code shows a comparison between `\tautrans` and `\tautransi`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\tautrans}{%
  \underset{\tau^*}{\longrightarrow}}
\newcommand*{\tautransi}{%
  \xrightarrow[{\raisebox{.4ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\scriptstyle\tau^*$}}]{\quad}}

\begin{document}

\[
\tautrans\quad\tautransi
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, xrightarrow's great. Here is what I ended up with: `\newcommand*{\tautrans}[1]
  {\xrightarrow[{\raisebox{.4ex}[0pt][0pt]{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle \tau^*}}}]{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #1}}}`